# Dozer enum to enum mapping

Tags: java, dozer

Why doesn't this work with Dozer? What would I have to do to make it happen? We have a gazillion enums, and sometimes we just need to map between them. Any way we could just configure dozer to do this without writing custom stuff?

```
enum EnumOne{ TEST1, TEST2 }
enum EnumTwo{ TEST1, TEST2 }

Mapper dozerMapper;

dozerMapper.map(EnumOne.TEST1, EnumTwo.class);
```

Comment: Did you solve it? if so, can you provide your solution? I'm running into the same problem. Enums are mapped fine when they are mapped as part of a larger POJO, but if I just want to map the Enum alone it doesn't work.

Comment: No, ended up writing a custom mapper for enums. Our mappers have a dozer mapper internally, and now they derive from a base class that can map enums by name.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because Dozer relies on the existence of a public constructor, which is illegal for an enum. You can infer this from the exception when you try to map them:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dozer.MappingException: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: DestinationEnum.< init >()
```

It's looking for a constructor that doesn't exist.

There's no way around it except as black666 said, it has be part of a bigger POJO. That's the way it's been shown in the [documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/enum.html).